# Adding ' " ' quote inside a paste command in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to have `"` (double quote) inside a pasted command in R

```
paste("perl -ane 'system("cat /auto/Sample_output/tmp.$F[0].vcf >> Sample_90061.vcf");'",sep="")
```

it says

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "paste("perl -ane 'system("cat"
```

I tried to create the quoted part alone and then paste it by

```
complicated = paste('"cat /auto/Sample_output/tmp.$F[0].vcf >> Sample_90061.vcf"',sep="")
```

but it shows as

```
> complicated
[1] "\"cat /auto/Sample_output/tmp.$F[0].vcf >> Sample_90061.vcf\""
```

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: to put " in ". you use \"  for instance: "The boy said, \"Hello World!\""

Comment: `shQuote`, `sQuote`, and `dQuote` might be functions to look into as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape `"` with backslash `\`. So you will have:

```
paste("perl -ane 'system(\"cat /auto/Sample_output/tmp.$F[0].vcf >> Sample_90061.vcf\");'",sep="")
```

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it possible to include `"` if the string is enclosed in single-quotes, but didn't try it here since this answer is "more correct".