# Using paste and substitute in combination with quotation marks in R

Tags: r, function, paste, substitution, quotation-marks

Please note that I already had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453020/paste-quotation-marks-into-character-string-within-a-loop) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205912/adding-quote-inside-a-paste-command-in-r) but still cannot solve my problem.

Suppose a minimal working example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(2,3,4)
c <- c(4,5,6)
dftest <- data.frame(a,b,c)

foo <- function(x, y, data = data) {
    data[, c("x","y")]
    }
foo(a, b, data = dftest)
```

Here, the last line obviously returns an `Error: undefined columns selected`. This error is returned because the columns to be selected are `x` and `y`, which are not part of the data frame `dftest`.

Question: How do I need to formulate the definition of the function to obtain the desired output, which is

```
> dftest[, c("a","b")]
#   a b
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 3
# 3 3 4
```

which I want to obtain by calling the function `foo`.

Please be aware that in order for the solution to be useful for my purposes, the format of the function call of `foo` is to be regarded fixed, that is, the only changes are to be made to the function itself, not the call. I.e. `foo(a, b, data = dftest)` is the only input to be allowed.

Approach: I tried to use `paste` and `substitute` in combination with `eval` to first replace the `x` and `y` with the arguments of the function call and then evaluate the call. However, escaping the quotation marks seems to be a problem here:

```
foo <- function(x, y, data = data) {
    substitute(data[, paste("c(\"",x,"\",\"",y,"\")", sep = "")])
    }
foo(a, b, data = dftest)    
eval(foo(a, b, data = dftest))
```

Here, `foo(a, b, data = dftest)` returns:

```
dftest[, paste("c(\"", a, "\",\"", b, "\")", sep = "")]
```

However, when evaluating with `eval()` (focusing only on the `paste` part),

```
paste("c(\"", a, "\",\"", b, "\")", sep = "")
```

returns:

```
# "c(\"1\",\"2\")" "c(\"2\",\"3\")" "c(\"3\",\"4\")"
```

and not, as I would hope `c("a","b")`, thus again resulting in the same error as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foo <- function(x, y, data = data) {
    x <- deparse(substitute(x))
    y <- deparse(substitute(y))
    data[, c(x, y)]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Everyday there is a new function to discover in R ... !
Still, it can be a bit disencouraging when you get an answer on SO within a few minutes on a question you have been trying to solve yourself for an hour... :/

Comment: @rawr, did you try that option?